# csh: how to pass an array argument

Tags: csh

I am writing a c-shell script with the following construct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env csh
set flags=(VAR1=\"-g $argv[2]\" VAR2=\"-g $argv[2]\")
make $flags
```

however, it isn't evaluated correctly. If I do `set echo`, I get the following out:

```
set flags= ( VAR1="-g -DABC" VAR2="-g -DABC" ) 
make VAR1="-g -DABC" VAR2="-g -DABC"
gnumake: invalid option -- 'D'                                                                                        
gnumake: invalid option -- 'A'                                                                                        
gnumake: invalid option -- 'D'                                                                                        
gnumake: invalid option -- 'A'                                                                                        
Usage: gnumake [options] [target] ...
```

yet, if I copy the last command to the terminal (`make VAR1="-g -DABC" VAR2="-g -DABC"`), it works.

Is there a way I can do the expansion/quoting correctly? Note, that I need to call `make` with `$flags` as env variable - for some conditions it may even be empty and the make variables I am setting inside `$flags` need to be arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: try changing your last line to `make "$flags"` ? It may not be possible in csh. Why are you using it. It's 2nd rate in many ways. If it is the cmd-line manipulation features, you can get all the  features (and more) in `bash` and `zsh) (I think) (and `ksh` after setting the correct options). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but no - it didn't help - it glues both VARs into 1 argument :( . Legacy is the reason for csh :) - the code I pasted is just a simplified snippet.

Comment: OK, figured legacy was the problem. But why do you need to have 1 var for `$flags`, while it may be possible, it will probably required super convoluted processing to to work the way you want. (ie escaping with 5 or 7 `'\'` chars)  Why not break it up into multiple vars? That's about all I have time for. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I was just hoping there is a trick I don't know that will make it simple :) The reason for keeping it in 1 variable, is that it makes it easier to completely switch off, i.e. under certain condition I need not to pass `VAR1` at all, so `make VAR1=$flag` won't work in this case.

Comment: It seems like you have read  [Grymoire: Arguments generalized as array lists](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#toc-uh-22), but if not, check that out. He seems to conclude that spaces are impossible in variables. Some typosin that article, so it's not super clear to me if somelike like `(set a=($argv[1]); set b=($argv[2])....` can help. Good luck! (now is the time to get your organization to switch shells. When I did, everyone was relieved, It can't hurt to ask!). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work either - probably the limitation of C-shell